# Can women wear panjtan pak name stone ring?

Tags: practical-islam, women

My friend gifted me a stone and the names of panjtan pak (The meaning of the word “Panjtan” is “five people”, and those are meant to be Hazrat Muhammad (S.A.W) , Hazrat Hassan (RA), Hazrat Hussain(RA) Saiyidah Fatimah Zahrah and Hazrat Ali .) is written on it. Some peoples says that it is prohibited in islam to wear pak names stones in ring or in necklace.
Can you tell me is this true that womens are not wear these stones or not. I want to make necklace of that stone can islam allows me or not?
[image]

Comment: What is "panjtan pak"?

Comment: The meaning of the word “Panjtan” is “five people”, and those are meant to be Hazrat Muhammad (S.A.W)  , Hazrat Hassan (RA), Hazrat Hussain(RA) Saiyidah Fatimah Zahrah and Hazrat Ali .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is no restriction for women to wear ring engraved or written name of PunjtanPak. Islam even permits women to wear gold and silver rings.Only those rings are prohibited in which un Islamic texture is written...